# Unable to use Device Microphone while using the USB web camera in Android

Tags: android, android-usb

We using the **USB web camera** in our Android application at the same time we provide the **Google Speech to Text** conversion feature as well. But we unable to use the Device Microphone while using the USB camera, so please help us how to forcefully enable the device mic programmatically.

or

how to enable below developer option programmatically?

**"Disable USB audio routing"**

Advanced Thanks.

Comment: Why not use USB Mic for Speech2Text conversion?

Comment: @emandt Thanks for your quick response. The USB camera is little faraway, so the voice can't reach the USB Mic. That's why I am looking solution for using phone Mic.